# What does "submission (terror)" mean as method of winning or losing a fight in MMA?

Tags: mixed-martial-arts, ufc

I've been reading about the old days of UFC and came across a fighter named Joe Son. If you look at his MMA record on his [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Son#Mixed_martial_arts_record), you'll notice that listed under method for his losses are:

- TKO (Shoulder injury)
- submission (terror)
- submission (elbow injury)
- submission (blood choke)

If I go to the Wikipedia page of his opponent, [Joe Moreira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Moreira#Mixed_martial_arts_record), and see his MMA record, you'll also see he won his fight against Joe Son by "Submission (terror)". You can see that, in both cases, the defeat/win occurred in round 1 and the time given is N/A.

This is really making me wonder what happened. The only way a time of N/A could be right is if the match never even started, yet Round 1 is given as the Round in which the defeat/win occurred, so I have no idea what's happened.

I searched around, but couldn't come up with an answer; I only came across a forum containing unsubstantiated stories about what happened, with some interesting ones, as this Joe Son guy was convicted of a number of crimes and is currently in prison.

Videos of other matches Joe Son competed in can be found, such as this one titled [UFC4 Legal groin shots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=57Mva-3n7TY)
Note: It's a bit graphic

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer can be found in the Wikipedia page you linked to, in the section "Mixed Martial Arts Career"

> On April 12, 2002, Son also took part in Xtreme Pankration 2, wherein he faced Joe Moreira. After a brief exchange of strikes, Moreira landed a hit which drew blood, and Son then refused to continue fighting, and the fight was called. The result was officially listed as "submission (terror)".

I shall point out that this is marked with "citation needed" in the Wikipedia article; I can't find any other evidence either way.

Comment: Hmm, sorry I missed that explanation in the article. I wonder why the time wasn't recorded. Is that a term you're familiar with? Submission(terror) when talking about combat sports? Like what's it called in boxing or kickboxing when a fighter doesn't want to continue?

Comment: It actually says "clarification needed", but obviously a citation would be needed also. At mixedmartialarts.com forums https://www.mixedmartialarts.com/forums/UnderGround/Joe-Son---Submission-Terror:1722812-1 someone says: "I do believe that that's the fight in which Joe M "bitch slapped" Joe Son right off the opening bell so hard that he walked back to his corner and tapped." Though this too needs verification.

Comment: So it does! I guess I didn't read it properly and my brain filled it in with what I wanted it to say!

Comment: Oh, I see now! This fight wasn't at a UFC event, it was at something called Xtreme Pankration 2, and this "submission(terror)" must be specific to this event maybe.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer. Here's another unsourced source from an old Sherdog thread that says the same thing: http://forums.sherdog.com/threads/tell-me-about-joe-moreira.1844089/